# Vueify and Babel 7

Tags: vue.js, gulp, babeljs, vueify

I am using Gulp, Browserify, Vueify and Babel to build my vue.js project.
I cannot move to another building system, so Gulp it is.
I recently updated from Babel 6 to Babel 7, due to a new addition in my project : Jest and unit testing (Babel 7 is a requirement)

Unfortunately, this had as a side effect Vueify to stop working with Babel 7, because it seems they are not compatible, or something. [Npm Vueify package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vueify) has not been updated for 2 years and I found a [git issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/issues/237) that no-one has commented officially.

Has anyone faced and resolved the same issue? Any alternatives to Vueify?
Thanks

Comment: You can fork the repo Vueify and fix the issue yourself, then rebuild the library for your project. Otherwise, there are plenty of alternatives to Vueify, for example Element Vue, Boostrap-Vue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right ! Vueify stopped maintaining their repository. Although, I was able to use the following fork : `"vueify":"github:stendahls/vueify#master"` which adds support for Babel 7 and `@babel/preset-env`. I will fork it myself but my tests were conclusive.

**Then, in my Gulpfile I could use the following** :

```
gulp.task('vueapp', () => {
    return browserify('assets/vueapp/js/main.js')
        .transform(vueify)
        .transform(babelify, {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('vueapp.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/vueapp/js/'));
});
```